# ColdFusion 2016 REST Services API: Error java.text.ParseException: Expected separator '/' instead of ';'

Tags: java, coldfusion

I'm working on a ColdFusion 2016 REST Services API and I want to call the API from Java. However, I get an error when calling the ColdFusion API from Java. The log error in ColdFusion is:

> java.text.ParseException: Expected separator '/' instead of ';'

Below is the sample code:

ColdFusion code:

```
 <cfcomponent rest="true" restPath="/">
 <cffunction name="test" access="remote" returntype="String" httpmethod="GET" restPath="test">
    <cfset rest = "API is working.">
    <cfreturn rest>
 </cffunction>
 </cfcomponent>
```

Java code:

```
 package javaapplication2;
 import javax.net.ssl.HostnameVerifier;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLContext;
 import javax.net.ssl.SSLSession;
 import javax.net.ssl.TrustManager;
 import javax.net.ssl.X509TrustManager;
 import java.security.cert.X509Certificate;
 import java.io.BufferedReader;
 import java.io.InputStreamReader;
 import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
 import java.net.URL;

 import javax.net.ssl.HttpsURLConnection;
 public class JavaApplication2 {
 public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
 TrustManager[] trustAllCerts = new TrustManager[] {
   new X509TrustManager() {
      public java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] getAcceptedIssuers() {
        return null;
      }

      public void checkClientTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

      public void checkServerTrusted(X509Certificate[] certs, String authType) {  }

   }
};
SSLContext sc = SSLContext.getInstance("SSL");
sc.init(null, trustAllCerts, new java.security.SecureRandom());
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultSSLSocketFactory(sc.getSocketFactory());
HostnameVerifier allHostsValid = new HostnameVerifier() {
    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
      return true;
    }
};
HttpsURLConnection.setDefaultHostnameVerifier(allHostsValid);
            String url = "http://localhost:8501/rest/api/test";
    URL obj = new URL(url);
    HttpURLConnection con = (HttpURLConnection) obj.openConnection();
    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
    int responseCode = con.getResponseCode();
    System.out.println("\nSending 'GET' request to URL : " + url);
    System.out.println("Response Code : " + responseCode);

    BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(
            new InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
    String inputLine;
    StringBuffer response = new StringBuffer();

    while ((inputLine = in.readLine()) != null) {
        response.append(inputLine);
    }     
    in.close();
    //print result
    System.out.println(response.toString());
 }
}
```

Please advise and Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: What happens when you just navigate directly to your REST URL from a browser?